# Facebook app_insights metric keys returning 0 data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is anyone having trouble getting Facebook metric data from the app_insights edge? Hoping to get a sanity check about the Facebook graph API. In the past we could use story_clicks, story_publishes and story_impressions to get data about our facebook app. For example we would use the request of

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/APP_ID/app_insights/story_publishes
```

to return data about our facebook application. We know the application is making posts, and the request doesn't return an error, but all we get are data points that look like this:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "time": "2019-12-02T08:00:00+0000",
        "value": "0"
    }
]
```

}

The app_insights endpoint is still listed in the [5.0 graph api documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version5.0), and nothing related to this seems to be listed in the [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v5.0/application/app_insights)

Comment: any update on this by any chance? go very similar problem

Comment: I wish! It seems like facebook is just not returning this data, and still can't find anything in the docs pertaining to a change. We have had a terrible experience dealing with facebook's volatile behavior when it comes to their app_insights endpoint.

Comment: This is so frustrating, we also have terrible experience, I tried anything I could think of on our client's fb application as well as my own test application with mocked activity, with the same result... Also tried other edge (application i think, where you can get some fields relevant to us as well) where I either get zeros or empty data set or even some correct values for some fields (edit: I almost forgot about some fields returning data just for some random time preiod, when application didnt even exist) ... Ridiculous